# Change de default status: Published to Not Published in Publishing Options

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to alter somehow the Publishing Options of the content type so that the default status of the article is Not Published?

I would like to do it in a preprocess function if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default status on /admin/structure/types/manage/YOURCONTENTTYPE in the publishing opitons. Just uncheck "Published".